# How do I modify the Environment.CommandLine property?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

For unit tests I would like to mimic different commandline arguments. How do I modify the commandLine args to my program at runtime (looked around but can't find the trick)? Basically I am trying to find a way to modify the contents of the READONLY property Environment.CommandLine.

Comment: Have you thought about replacing that with an injectionable (is that even a word?) service that you can replace with a mock in your unit-tests? Though if you absolutely need to do what you want to do, I would guess TypeMock Isolator (http://typemock.com) could do it.

Comment: Can you not just execute the program with different command lines?

Comment: You really need to refactor your methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, this is 'hard' read-only.  It comes out of Windows, GetCommandLine API function, it doesn't allow modifying it either.  You'll have to mock it.

Comment: This is probably the right way to do it, unfortunately I don't have time allocated for that so looking for a quick way.

Comment: It is just a string, surely you can mock a string.

Comment: Just to nitpick: you actually can modify the command line natively (the pointer returned by GetCommandLine() is not constant; see also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/23/9440784.aspx). Whether it is wise to do so is another thing; and thankfully it is not (easily) possible in managed code anyway.

Comment: You guys are awesome. Just need a good smack every now and again to just sit down and do it. Wrote the mock - life became so much easier. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me as if you're trying to test things the hard way. Presumably somewhere you have a function that is reading directly from Environment.CommandLine. Refactor that method to take a string parameter (which in the real application will be populated from Environment.CommandLine), and test that method independently.